# Visual Code, install requests with anaconda but still remind "ImportError: No module named requests"

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-requests

when I use visual code. import requests, it has been installed with anaocnda, but Visual Studio code still remind me "ImportError: No module named requests"
But the code can work in debug mode in Visual Studio code and terminal.

Reinstall requests and anaconda. It doesn't work.

import requests
url = '***'
a = requests.get(url)

```
import requests
```

ImportError: No module named requests

Answer (score 0):

Change your vscode terminal to cmd instead of powershell and make sure the base is set to conda.